# Pythonic data cleaning of address ranges

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I need to know if the following task is possible via Python.

I have a list of 4,300 addresses, each that covers a range of addresses, like this:

1. 8519-21 S Broadway
2. 8700-6 Riverview Blvd
3. 822-4 Angelica St
4. 8442-6 N Broadway

I want to isolate the first address and the last in the range. So, using 1 as an example, I would need the output to give me 8519 S Broadway and 8521 S Broadway, each in its own row.

In some instances, like 1 and 3, I only need the first two digits of the first number to complete the second address. I tried in Excel using text to columns (-), then CONCATENATE and LEFT(cell,2) but then I don't get the address correct for instances like 2 and 4, where I need the first three digits of the address. Is there any way to write a python script to solve this?

Comment: How is your data stored?

Comment: It's in a .csv right now (all in one column, each address range in its own row) so it could be in a list, a dict, a dataframe; whatever is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
addresses=["8519-21 S Broadway","8700-6 Riverview Blvd"]
output=[]
for i in addresses:
    output.append(i[0:i.find('-')]+i[i.find(' '):])
    numEnd=i[i.find('-')+1:i.find(' ')]
    numStart=i[0:i.find('-')-len(numEnd)]+numEnd+i[i.find(' '):]
    output.append(numStart)
print(output)
```

Where `addresses` is a list of the address ranges in the format you've given, and `output` is the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your input `.csv` file looks like this:

```
Address
8519-21 S Broadway
8700-6 Riverview Blvd
822-4 Angelica St
8442-6 N Broadway
```

and you want it to look something like this:

```
First Address,Last Address
8519 S Broadway,8521 S Broadway
8700 Riverview Blvd,8706 Riverview Blvd
822 Angelica St,824 Angelica St
8442 N Broadway,8446 N Broadway
```

You can accomplish this by using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module:

```
from csv import writer

# open both input and output csv
with open("addresses.csv") as csv_in, open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as csv_out:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_out)

    # Skip 'Address' header
    next(csv_in)

    # Write new headers
    csv_writer.writerow(["First Address", "Last Address"])

    # Go through each line in csv
    for line in csv_in:

        # Split ranges from rest of line
        ranges, *rest = line.split()

        # Split ranges themselves
        start, end = ranges.split("-")

        # Get difference between length of numbers
        diff = len(start) - len(end)

        # Create new end address
        end = start[:diff] + end

        # Write new lines to output csv
        csv_writer.writerow([" ".join([start, *rest]), " ".join([end, *rest])])
```

Which will output your results into *output.csv*.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and suggestions, all. This is how I ended up tackling it:

```
import re
import csv
from csv import DictReader

dash_add = []

def get_address_list(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            adds = row['Siteaddr']
            if "-" in adds:
                dash_add.append(adds)

z = []

def get_formatted_address(address):
        numeric = address.split(" ")[0]
        text = address.replace(numeric, "").strip()
        start = numeric.split("-")[0]
        end = numeric.split("-")[1]
        end = start[:-len(end)] + end
        return [start + " " + text,  end + " " + text]

get_address_list('./data/map_data_112318.csv')
[z.extend(get_formatted_address(i)) for i in dash_add]

with open('formatted_addresses.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['Address'])
    for v in z:
        writer.writerows([[v]])
```